# Azure Functions not Running Fast Enough

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function that reads jobs from a storage queue. It then executes these jobs and grabs more. I have been getting more jobs for it to run lately and noticed that the queue is building up.

What can I do from an Azure Perspective to get better performance out of this?  Each job runs in its own little world so adding a new instance or adding threads or attaching to a "better" machine would all work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Things that come to mind with the information provided:

- For more pure power: Host your Azure Function in a [dedicated App Service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale) instead of using the consumption plan. You can scale up (better hardware) or out (more hardware). Be aware that this [could also be worse](https://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/azure-functions-scaling-with-a-dedicated-app-service-plan/) in theory. I would give it a try. Or try the "premium consumption plan" mentioned by Ken.
- More parallelism: If your queue builds up even though you are not using most of your resources. Try playing with the [configuration parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#host-json) `batchSize` and `newBatchThreshold`.
- Changed execution logic: Depending where most of your time is spent during function execution, [durable functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-concepts) **might** help. Based on your comments you might also try to cache the external data using `static` or Azure Redis Cache.
- Look at the most [common performance considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices)

Answer (score 1):

Premium plan (Preview)

Azure Functions Premium plan provides customers the same features and scaling mechanism used on the Consumption plan (based on number of events) with enhanced performance and VNET access. Azure Functions Premium Functions plan is billed on a per second basis based on the number of vCPU-s and GB-s your premium functions consume.

In order to use the Azure Functions Premium Plan private preview your subscription needs to be added to an allowlist. Please apply for access via http://aka.ms/functionspremium.

More Info:

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/blob/master/functions-premium-plan/overview.md

Comment: I don't know if we are to that point yet.  We are currently on the consumption plan and I hope to get to the premium plan some day but what can I do at this point?  I want to avoid reworking my function to make it better since most of this issue is not the function but the outside websites it calls. (some are async were possible already).

Comment: I assume you already looked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices